# Incorrect longitude coordinates on NetCDF from CAMS it can't allow masking

Tags: python, netcdf, xarray

I've downloaded from [Copernicus Atmosphere Monitoring Service](https://ads.atmosphere.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/cams-europe-air-quality-forecasts?tab=overview) some analysis about particulate matter in `.nc` file format.
I need to mask that data and save in the same file format.

Using `Xarray` library I open my file:

```
    import xarray as xr

    data = xr.open_dataset(
        filename_or_obj=input_data,
        engine="netcdf4"
    )
    data.rio.write_crs(4326, inplace=True)
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (longitude: 700, latitude: 420, level: 1, time: 744)
Coordinates:
  * longitude    (longitude) float32 335.0 335.1 335.2 ... 44.75 44.85 44.95
  * latitude     (latitude) float32 71.95 71.85 71.75 ... 30.25 30.15 30.05
  * level        (level) float32 0.0
  * time         (time) timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00 01:00:00 ... 30 days 23:00:00
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Data variables:
    pm10_conc    (time, level, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    title:        PM10 Air Pollutant ANALYSIS at the Surface
    institution:  Data produced by Meteo France
    source:       Data from ENSEMBLE model
    history:      Model ENSEMBLE ANALYSIS
    ANALYSIS:     Europe, 20210301-20210331+[0H_23H]
    summary:      ENSEMBLE model hourly ANALYSIS of PM10 concentration at the...
    project:      MACC-RAQ (http://macc-raq.gmes-atmosphere.eu)
```

I use `.sel` to extract a subset of `data` focused on the area of interest:

```
latitude_slice = slice(lat_min, lat_max)
longitude_slice = slice(lon_min, lon_max)

data = data.sel(latitude=latitude_slice, longitude=longitude_slice)
```

But I see the error below:

```
self = Index([335.04998779296875,  335.1499938964844,             335.25,
        335.3500061035156, 335.45001220703125, 335....            44.75, 44.849998474121094,
        44.95000076293945],
      dtype='float32', name='longitude', length=700)
key = 13.762112597623

    def get_loc(self, key):
        """
        Get integer location, slice or boolean mask for requested label.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        key : label
    
        Returns
        -------
        int if unique index, slice if monotonic index, else mask
    
        Examples
        --------
        >>> unique_index = pd.Index(list('abc'))
        >>> unique_index.get_loc('b')
        1
    
        >>> monotonic_index = pd.Index(list('abbc'))
        >>> monotonic_index.get_loc('b')
        slice(1, 3, None)
    
        >>> non_monotonic_index = pd.Index(list('abcb'))
        >>> non_monotonic_index.get_loc('b')
        array([False,  True, False,  True])
        """
        casted_key = self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)
        try:
            return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
        except KeyError as err:
>           raise KeyError(key) from err
E           KeyError: 13.762112597623
```

Since the area covered by the `nc` file is incorrect(checking min and max longitude I read 0.05 and 359.95) I can't made a subset.

If I read the `nc` file with QGIS as raster(instead of mesh) and extract the boundary box with `Extract layer extent`, I can read the right coordinates.

Is there an explanation on the fact that this kind of file has incorrect coordinates? I've the same problem if I download other data in NetCDF.